# Mapping the buttons to the Dataverse Tables. Need the Power FX syntax

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

Ok, so I am making a model driven application with Powerapps and made a custom canvas homepage in my solution. Now I am trying to map the buttons to the forms and views in Dataverse, I created for the solution. I also need to map the command line buttons the the table views and forms too.

So i tried this Power FX code to map the buttons in the canvas custom page to dataverse tables;

```
Switch(
    ThisItem.ButtonTitle,

    "Form",
    Navigate(Defaults('Productions (Forms)')

)
```

Don't know how to make it, Can someone who knows PowerApps and Power FX language help me, I will be more than happy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the question is not clear on where the button is, I assume that the help needed is with Power FX statements for opening entity view and forms. Below are the Power FX formulas to navigate to Model driven app forms or views.

**Navigate**

> Note
>
> For additional options, see the client API reference to use
> JavaScript. More information: navigateTo (Client API reference)

**Navigate to a custom page**

To navigate to a custom canvas page within a model-driven app, pass the page name as the first argument.

```
Navigate( myCustomPage )
```

**Navigate to the default view of the table**

To navigate to the default view of the table, pass the table name as the first argument.

```
Navigate( Accounts )
```

**Navigate to specific system view of the table**

To navigate to a specific system view of the table, pass the table's Views enum.

```
Navigate( 'Accounts (Views)'.'My Active Accounts' )
```

**Navigate to the default form of the table**

To navigate to the default form of the table, pass the record as the first argument.

```
Navigate( Gallery1.Selected )
```

**Navigate to the default form of the table in create mode**

To navigate to the default form of the table, pass a Dataverse record created from the Defaults function. This will open the default form with the record as a new record. The Defaults function takes the table name to create the record.

```
Navigate( Defaults( Accounts ) )
```

**Power FX for modern commanding**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/commanding-use-powerfx

**Power FX for Custom Page**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/page-powerfx-in-model-app

Comment: Thnx for the reply. Though I used all of these, in my case they didn't work out. Anyways, I changed the app at the end and don't need anymore.